# How to show the resultant value of a webservice in tabhost on android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, android-tabhost

I want to consume a webservice and show that answer in tabhost on android.How to do this?

can anyone help me.i've done some sources.

Thank u!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON objects to retrieve value from the webservice and then you can use them in your tab.

Comment: u can get the idea of how to use webservice from this link  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/